# Change default docker0 bridge ip address

Tags: docker-ce

After starting docker-ce (18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a) on Ubuntu Server 16.04, the following is created:

```
$ ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:fe:36:81:72
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Unfortunately, my PC is on this network. Meaning that as soon as the docker starts, I lose ssh connectivity to the server.

#### Attempt 1

Several forums are saying to add the following to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
  "bip": "192.168.1.1/24"
}
```

#### Attempt 2, using [this SO accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43672291/4470542)

One possible solution that is working is running:

```
sudo ip addr add dev docker0 192.168.1.1/24
sudo ip addr del dev docker0 172.17.0.1/16
```

Source: [forums.docker.com](https://forums.docker.com/t/change-default-docker0-bridge-ip-address/30470/8)

Although this is a possible solution, I have to do it after the docker service starts. Something I can't do because I lose connectivity meanwhile.

#### Attempt 3, following @Light.G [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52270884/4470542)

After adding the `-bip` to `ExecStart` line, trying to start docker gives (journalctl -xe):

```
-- Unit docker.socket has begun starting up.
Sep 11 11:13:19 PTLISLABHLC01 systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 11 11:13:19 PTLISLABHLC01 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 11 11:13:19 PTLISLABHLC01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Sep 11 11:13:19 PTLISLABHLC01 systemd[1]: docker.socket: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 11 11:13:19 PTLISLABHLC01 polkitd(authority=local)[1062]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:15666:32644036 (system bus name :1.56, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

Only error here is that you should use `--bip` and not `-bip`. Check the accepted answer!

Comment: Attempt #1 worked for me after restarting docker: "sudo service docker restart"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No need extra entity:**

- Edit /lib/systemd/system/docker.service before start Docker. Add `--bip "192.168.1.1/24"` at the end of line `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd`.
- `systemctl daemon-reload`
- `systemctl start docker`

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 with Docker 17.03-ce.

**Edit on 2018-09-13:**
Since we might still need user-defined bridge networks, there is still a potential issue.

> By default bridge is assigned one subnet from the ranges 172.[17-31].0.0/16 or 192.168.[0-240].20/20 which does not overlap with any existing interface. Unlike the default bridge network, user-defined networks supports manual IP address and subnet assignment. If an assignment is not given, then Docker’s default IPAM driver assigns the next subnet available in the private space.

Thougt they say it would not overlap with any existing interfaces on host, you still suffered such an issue. So if you need user-defined bridge networks, you’d better assign specific subnet for them. As I know, there is no parameters for customizing IPAM driver default pool.

Comment: @NBajanca Any error occurred? Or just the docker version issue? I am not sure. You have tried this, but the default bridge IP still the default?

Comment: @NBajanca could u pls pass me your **ExecStart** line in `docker.service`? It becomes more interesting.

Comment: ``ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://`` and I tried ``ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -bip “192.168.1.1/24”``

Comment: I tried again and got an error. I just update the question.

Comment: @NBajanca sorry, my bad. There are two ‘-‘ before ‘bip’.

Comment: Solved! Thank you

Comment: This looks good, can you add an systemd unti file example? a line of code is worth a thousand words :)

Comment: The SO classic - a terrible, knee-jerk solution that will cause OP more problems down the line when a Docker update will overwrite the unit file. The daemon.json based configuration below is the actual answer.

Comment: @EugenePankov Had U try  the "daemon.json based configuration" ? It could not solve the problem here. Maybe you could put more details upon that answer.

Comment: @Light.G daemon.json maps directly to dockerd flags. You can just set the same option there as shown in the 2nd answer

Comment: @EugenePankov As the author who submit this question writed above, he had already tried the way configuring deamon.json file, which does not work well. Maybe there is some other issue in such a case, maybe it's version issue. In a word, thx for commenting.

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to do it with a service that runs a shell command.

I created `docker-network-setup.sh`:

```
sudo ip addr add dev docker0 192.168.1.1/24
sudo ip addr del dev docker0 172.17.0.1/16
```

`chmod u+x docker-network-setup.sh` to ensure you can execute it.

And `docker-network-setup.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Change docker0 default IP
# When systemd stops or restarts the docker.service, the action is propagated to this unit
PartOf=docker.service
# Start this unit after the docker.service start
After=docker.service

[Service]
# The program will exit after running the script
Type=oneshot
# Execute the shell script
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user01/docker-network-setup.sh start
# This service shall be considered active after start
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
# This unit should start when docker.service is starting
WantedBy=docker.service
```

`sudo cp docker-network-setup.service /etc/systemd/system` and the service is enabled!

Don't forget `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` if you want to test the service right away.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with **AWS VPC peering** connection that didn't work with my Docker containers until I found this thread.

In case you're using an **AWS 172.17.x.x subnet**, it might conflict with the default Docker subnet (**172.17.0.1/16**), so nothing will work between those subnets...

One way to fix it will be just moving to a different AWS subnet (which is not always possible due to legacy systems/configurations);

Another way will be to change the default Docker subnet with bip setup in **/etc/docker/daemon.json** (as described above) - something like:

```
{
  "bip": "192.168.1.1/24"
}
```

Best approach will be just to avoid using 172.17.x.x subnet in AWS...

Comment: The file was not there. I created it by myself, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Adding --bip to docker.sevice did not work me, but I found this slight variation of the answer that did the trick for me:
https://blog.container-solutions.com/set-the-ip-of-the-docker-bridge-with-systemd

tldr;

1. you copy the `ExecStart` line from `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` and add `--bip=192.168.1.1/24` in a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf` along with the [Service] tag

Example:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --bip=192.168.169.1/24
```

2. You reload the daemon, stop docker, take the old docker0 bridge down then start docker again