# Docker change IP from Bridge

Tags: docker, networking, bridge

i have tried all of thes solutions to change the ip-address of my bridge:
[Change default docker0 bridge ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225493/change-default-docker0-bridge-ip-address)
But i allways got thes error:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-07-10 20:02:29 CEST; 9min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 3130 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --bip 192.168.198.128/25 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3130 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 10 20:02:26 Server systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 10 20:02:29 Server systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 10 20:02:29 Server systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Jul 10 20:02:29 Server systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 10 20:02:29 Server systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 10 20:02:29 Server systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 10 20:02:29 Server systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 10 20:03:09 Server systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 10 20:03:09 Server systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 10 20:03:09 Server systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

When i try to change it via

> dockerd --bip=192.168.198.128/25

Then i recived this:

```
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:14.220551981+02:00] Starting up
failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
root@Server:/etc/docker# sudo service docker stop
root@Server:/etc/docker# dockerd --bip=192.168.198.128/25
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.749647728+02:00] Starting up
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.751145974+02:00] detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.752521878+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.752770076+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.752906825+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.753028929+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.756109499+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.756411626+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.756544438+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.756653280+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.761446487+02:00] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2
WARN[2021-07-10T20:30:27.807419442+02:00] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit
WARN[2021-07-10T20:30:27.807711781+02:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period
WARN[2021-07-10T20:30:27.807832417+02:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime
INFO[2021-07-10T20:30:27.808384049+02:00] Loading containers: start.
ERRO[2021-07-10T20:30:28.211882902+02:00] failed to get event                           error="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: failed to allocate gateway (192.168.198.128): Address already in use
```

but i dont have it in use, not in my network and not as a ip in the config of any network-connections.
Did anybody has an idea how to change it?
Thanks bevore.

Comment: I found a possible answer. The interface of my docker-Server itself has a /24 network, maybe this is the problem, im trying now to change this.

Comment: After changing the Netmask it doesnt work either.

Comment: Generally speaking, system administration questions are better fit for [unix.se] or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) rather than Stack Overflow.